# How to configure one-to-one / @OneToOne association to insert foreign key automatically in both tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I  have two entities mapped by one-to-one association **SalesEntry** (parent) and **Receipt** (child). while saving SalesEntry object foreign key in SalesEntry get inserted but in **Receipt** not get inserted

**SalesEntry.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SALES_ENTRY")
public class SalesEntry {

    public SalesEntry() {       
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "SALES_ENTRY_ID")
    private long salesEntryId;
    @Column(name = "TOTAL_AMOUNT")
    private double totalAmount;


@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RECEIPT_ID", unique = true, nullable = true)
    private Receipt receipt;

...
}
```

**Receipt.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RECEIPT")
public class Receipt {

    public Receipt() {
        // empty constructor
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "RECEIPT_ID")
    private long receiptId;
    @Column(name = "RECEIPT_NO", unique = true)
    private String receiptNo;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SALES_ENTRY_ID")
    private SalesEntry salesEntry;

    ...
}
```

while saving **SalesEntry** object with **Receipt**  it saves **Receipt** object but foreign key in (SALES_ENTRY_ID) **Receipt**  table not get inserted.

any mistakes in my configuration? what i want to do? to work as i expected.

Comment: I think you should use only OneToOne. Remove ManyToOne from SalesEntry.java and use OneToOne in SalesEntry.java above Receipt property. If you need clear example go to https://github.com/harmishlakhani you can find all the example

Comment: A quick Google-search gave me this: http://fruzenshtein.com/bidirectional-one-to-one-primary-key-association/ Can't test it out now, but it seems to cover, what you want to achieve.